# Delete files that don't exist in another folder -Backup in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing my own batch script to backup some files to an external. here's what I've got so far:

```
@echo off
:: variables
set /p dname=Enter the Backup drive's drive letter:
set drive=%dname%:\Backup
set folder=%%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2_date:~10,4%%
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y /q

echo ### Backing up My Documents...
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" "%drive%\Last\Documents"

echo ### Backing up Favorites...
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites" "%drive%\Last\Favorites"

echo ### Setting backup folder of today's date...
%backupcmd% "%drive%\Last\Documents" "%drive%\%folder%\Documents"
%backupcmd% "%drive%\Last\Favorites" "%drive%\%folder%\Favorites"

echo Backup Complete!
```

So in the end two folders: Last and today's date will contain the same thing. I want the Last folder to contain exactly what's in my C drive currently, however I don't want to remove the functionality of xcopy only copying newly modified files. Is there a way to recurse through my Documents folder and delete from Last any files that don't exist in C:?

In other words, first run of the script creates

```
Last\Documents\file1.txt and (Date)\Documents\file1.txt
```

the second run (where file1.txt has been removed from drive C:) happens tomorrow and contains:

```
Last\Documents\(no file1.txt) and (NewDate)\Documents\(no file1.txt)
```

but

```
(Date)\Documents\file1.txt
```

remains intact

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the mirror options available in robocopy. Robocopy comes by default in Windows 7 now. It is a great way to go.

Comment: oh that's exactly what I wanted. I had no idea robocopy was finally part of the release

Comment: Excellent. Make sure you read the documentation. You don't want to lose data!

Comment: I'm all set of Mirror and Purge and now i'm just adding icing. If you want the credit, just put in the same answer below. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the mirror options available in robocopy. Robocopy comes by default in Windows 7 now. It is a great way to go.